# Potions of harming won't do damage

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I spent a few hours building a command block chain that would place and destroy a bunch redstone blocks that would activate of dispensers high up in the air and it worked, but once I tested it in survival mode the harming potions in the dispensers would fall but wouldn't hurt me. I have no clue why this is happening so please help.

Here's a video to show what I mean:

Comment: Hmm... Those splash potion particles don't look like instant damage particles

Comment: How did you get those potions? Try if the same happens in a new world. A lot is possible with resource packs and commands, there are endless possibilities what could cause this.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Sxcv011NzTk
I tried in a new world without command blocks and I don't have any texture packs on
and it did the same thing but I noticed the dispensers are leaving pink particles
but when I throw it, it's a dark red could that be the problem?

Comment: and i got them from the creative menu